# Get a 'Session matching query does not exist' error when users auto login via chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-models, google-chrome-devtools

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e6uy.jpg)

The website gets a 'Session matching query does not exist' error when users auto login via chrome. The error happens in the middleware that makes sure users can't login in different browsers.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session


class OneSessionPerUser:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_session_key = request.user.logged_in_user.session_key

        if current_session_key and current_session_key != request.session.session_key:
            Session.objects.get(session_key=current_session_key).delete()

        request.user.logged_in_user.session_key = request.session.session_key
        request.user.logged_in_user.save()

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```

Does anybody know what might be the problem here or does anybody know how to disable the chrome auto login?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
  if current_session_key and current_session_key != request.session.session_key:
            Session.objects.get(session_key=current_session_key).delete()
```

I had the same problem, and as I understand it, you should change the get for filter. Because if get doesn't get an answer, he throws this error. With filter, a filter can be an empty query. So I did:

```
if current_session_key and current_session_key != request.session.session_key:
        Session.objects.filter(session_key=current_session_key).delete()
```

after this, it was all good. No more strange bugs.

Edit:

After some good points made by my partner, what happened is that the session key got deleted or destroyed, so, when you apply the get, it doesn't get an answer because there is no empty value to get, that's why it spits the error. With filter, you are still searching a empty value, but in this case you can get empty queries, and because the values are unique, you won't take out two sessions at once.

Sorry if I have bad English, this is not my first language.